# How to pass variables to anonymous method in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I want to pass the request parameter to the method, but I fail every time. I am beginner in PHP.

```
public function changeModel(Request $request)
{
    $u1 = $request->U;
    
    Schema::table('planspieldatas', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->renameColumn('U1', $u1);
});

    Artisan::call('migrate');
    return redirect('/pssettings')->with('success-upload', 'Daten für Markt'.$u1);
}
```

I am not able to pass the $u1 variable to the Schema::table method. Is there any option to change the column names in SQL from the front end.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using Closure method so you need to use `use()` method to pass variables like

```
Schema::table('planspieldatas', function (Blueprint $table) use ($u1) {
        $table->renameColumn('U1', $u1);
});
```